# How to convert nil values to true without nilcheck

Tags: ruby

I have a variable `val`, which can be `nil`, `true`, or `false`. I'm writing a method `convert`, which converts the input `val` and returns the following value according to `val`:

- `true` -> `true`
- `false` -> `false`
- `nil` -> `true`

I can do this with a `nil` check like:

```
def convert
  val.nil? ? true : val
end
```

How can I convert it without a [`nil` check](https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/v4.8.2/docs/Nil-Check.md)?

Comment: What is the relation between `my_to_bool` and `convert`?

Comment: Your `convert` code will not work unless `val` is a method. If you intended to be a local variable, it is not defined within its scope, and will raise an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the only possible values are `true`, `false`, and `nil`, I might suggest

```
def convert
  val != false
end
```

Although, in fairness, this is violating the spirit of that guideline you mentioned. Having a value that can be `nil` *or* Boolean really feels like some kind of tri-state type, which would be better factored out into a set of better-named constants or even just symbols.

Comment: :+1: for pointing out that this is probably a case where a set of constants/symbols would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

another way :

```
def convert(val)
  [true, nil].include?(val)
end
```

Output:

```
> convert(true)
#=> true 
> convert(nil)
#=> true 
> convert(false)
#=> false
```